# How can I plot a hyperbolic curve in R and get an equation of best fit?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

Is there anyway to plot this data set using `ggplot2` to get a graph with a hyperbolic line of beset fit as well as the equation for the line?

```
X = 2.5000, 1.2500, 0.6250, 0.3125, 0.1560, 0.0781, 0.0391
Y = 1.0500, 0.8700, 0.5550, 0.3140, 0.1930, 0.0731, 0.0030
```

I know you can plot it using `plot(x=X, y=Y)`, but I cannot get a line of the best fit that is hyperbolic, nor I can  get an equation for the best fit.

Comment: For your hyperbolic model, ¿what parameters do you wish to estimate?  For example, ¿are you assuming the focal axis is the horizontal axis?

Comment: Could you tell us specifically, preferably with a mathematical formula or geometric description, what a "hyperbolic line" might be?

Comment: @whuber I assumed by "line" the OP meant "curve"

Comment: @Gregg I don't follow, because "curve" is just a vague generic term.  There are several possible meanings of "hyperbolic," too, which is why I have requested clarification.

Comment: @whuber I meant that in my response, I assumed "hyperbolic line" meant "hyperbolic curve"

Comment: Everything is positive and higher values of $Y$ are associated with higher values of $X$.  Plotting $Y$ or $\frac{1}{Y}$ against $X$ or $\frac{1}{X}$ in any of the four combinations does not seem to suggest anything close to linear on your data.  So what do you mean by "hyperbolic" here?

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that your data follows a hyperbolic model, then you can use the following approach (detailed more here https://engineerexcel.com/hyperbolic-curve-fitting-excel/):

- use a harmonic transform for $x$ and $y$, which means $x_t = \frac1x$ and $ y_t=\frac1y$
- run regression predicting $y_t$ from $x_t$
- set intercept equal to $\frac1m$ and solve for $m$
- set slope equal to $\frac{k}m$ and solve for $k$

Then, the hyperbola is given as $y = \frac{mx}{k+x}$.

Note, this approach assumes that the focal axis is the horizontal axis and that the point (0,0) goes thru the hyperbola (is one of the vertices of the hyperbola).